# how to use "java -Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having some difficulties with a piece of code, I got from an external firm.
In the Code I've got the advice to:

//Make sure your Base64.encode does not includes line breaks !
//Running this example use java -Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true

My question is, how/where can I pass that paramter from within Eclipse?

Thanks in advance

add: I'm using 
Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Lauch configuration an go to the `Arguments` tab, enter your argument

```
-Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true
```

in the field `VM arguments`

clkcit Apply and Run